# python regex OR on single charcters with spacy pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I am trying to figure out how to can condense the number of pattern matching rules I need to create to pick up on conditions like I saw a man at the SW corner of Pike street. For "SW Corner", I don't want to write a match rule for every directional variation (N, S, E, W, etc.). I tried to do it with the below, but it isn't right. Well, it works but it also picks up other things.

Example:

```
matcher.add("DIRECTION", None,
           [{}, {"TEXT":{"REGEX":"(?:N)|(?:S)|(?:E)|(?:W)|(?:NW)|(?:NE)|(?:SW)|(?:SE)"}}, {"LOWER":"corner"}]
           )
```

I want to be able to use the OR statements, but I am not sure how to do that with the single or double characters (N, S, E, W, NW, NE, SW, SE).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not overuse non-capturing groups, `(?:SW)` is the same as `SW`.

Also, you do not want to match `SE` in `SED` token, use *anchors*, `^` and `$`.

Use

```py
{"REGEX":"^(?:N|S|E|W|NW|NE|SW|SE)$"}
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/MIxyeV/1).

Case insensitive variant:

```py
{"REGEX":"(?i)^(?:N|S|E|W|NW|NE|SW|SE)$"}
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    N                        'N'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    S                        'S'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    E                        'E'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    W                        'W'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NW                       'NW'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NE                       'NE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SW                       'SW'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SE                       'SE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thanks! My regex skills are obviously lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Use character sets https://regex101.com/r/Nx19GG/1

```
(?:[NS][EW]?)|(?:[EW])
```

See the Python documentation for a primer on regex syntax: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax